# FeedMe is updating slug/URI

Tags: plugin-feedme

We are using the FeedMe plugin twice a day to feed in updates on certain fields around 3000 pages. Every time we run this the slug gets updated with a "-2" on the end. So now after only a week we have pages that have 10+ "-2"s on the end. Is there a way to prevent the updating of the slug when using FeedMe?

Comment: Do the original entries get updated and are you sure it‘s not new ones being created?

Comment: @MatthiasRedl-Mann the originals get updated but the slug also gets updated. We have the settings on update and create, which says will update existing if exist and create if new. We do not see duplicates on the system for a particular entry.

Comment: ok, that then my first guess was wrong.... sorry, no other idea at the moment

Comment: @MatthiasRedl-Mann seems that old slugs do appear if you go directly to the url so maybe it is duplicating in the background. But if you look at the craft admin and search it shows only one entry.